# Generalized Leibniz's Rule

Tags: multiple-integral, leibniz-integral-rule

Let $\Omega$ be a open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$, $u: \Omega  \to \mathbb{R}$ a function, $ u \in C^2(\Omega)$. Given $x_0 \in \Omega$, let $r > 0$ be such that $B_r(x_0) \subset \subset \Omega$. For $0< s\leq r$, consider the following function:

$\varphi(s) = \dfrac{1}{n\omega_ns^{n-1}}\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_s(x_0)} u(x) \hspace{0.1cm}dS_x$, where $\omega_n = |B_1(0)|$.

Making the change of variable $x = x_0 + sz$, $z \in \partial B_1(0)$, we conclude easily that

$\varphi(s) = \dfrac{1}{n\omega_n}\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_1(0)} u(x_0 + sz)\hspace{0.1cm} dS_z$.

Ok. I'm having trouble justifying why the following equality is valid:

$\varphi'(s) = \dfrac{1}{n\omega_n}\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \nabla u(x_0 + sz)\cdot z \hspace{0.1cm}dS_z$.

My question then is: How to justify this equality? This looks like a Leibniz rule of calculus, but I feel unsure about applying it in this context.

Comment: It follows from the chain rule: $\frac{d}{ds}u(x_0+sz)=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial}{\partial (sz_i)}u(x_0+sz)\frac{d}{ds}(sz_i)\,.$ Clumsy but hopefully shows what I mean.

Comment: Yes, but my doubt here is: why can i pass the limit under integral sign?

Comment: Since $u$ is assumed to be $C^2$ it is bounded on the compact $\partial B_1(0)$. So is every partial derivative of $u$. Therefore, all requirements of [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) are fulfilled.